# Triggering a build on completion of another build when a Pull Request comes in

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a web application in an Azure DevOps repo and there's a branch policy on the `master` branch that kicks off a build when a pull request is created. This validates that it compiles and performs code quality checks and the like.

We also have some integration tests (using Mocha and Selenium) that live in another repo. I would like to run the integration tests when a PR against `master` is created.

As far as I know I cannot have the same build pull from two different repos (without using extensions and it seems cleaner to me to have two separe builds anyway). So I thought I would have another build just to run the integration tests. The build that pulls from the webapp repo would have a final step where it would deploy to an integration tests environment and then the second build would get the latest version of the integration tests and run them against the integration tests environment. I created a Build Completion trigger on the integration tests build that is triggered by the completion of the webapp build.

The problem is that when I queue the webapp build manually, it will launch the integration tests build when done. But when the webapp build is queued by an incoming PR, the integration tests build does not get triggered.

Is this a bug in Azure DevOps or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: IMO tests **should not** be in a different repository.

Answer (score 0):

Also in my side builds from PR doesn't trigger another builds (with Build Completion trigger), I don't know if it's a bug or it's by design.

Anyway, there is a workaround - the final step in the first build will trigger the second build. how? with [Trigger Build](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) task.

You just need to change the branch because it will be a merge branch from the PR that doesn't exist in the tests repository:

[image]

You can also do it without install extensions with PowerShell task and the [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue).